# Same file on multiple sites

Tags: php, html

Let's say I have 2 domain names 123.com and abc.com all on the same 1and1 server.
123.com is in a folder called 123 and abc.com is in a folder named abc.

How would I include a file stored in 123 into a page on the abc.com site.
I used to do this with PHP

```
<?php 
$code = file_get_contents("http://www.123.com/file.html"); 
eval('?>' . $code); 
?>
```

but it was stopped with PHP5 to prevent abuse.

Basically, I want to be able to edit one file of html and have it change on multiple sites.

I thought that

```
<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]/123/file.html); ?>
```

would do it, but it's not going to my server root, just the domain's root.
Is it possible to use php to get info from sibling folders on a server?

Thanks
Richard

Comment: Is it *the same* server? Do you have access to the other domain's files?

Comment: If the folders are all on the same server, then why not point those folders in each website at the same location on disk? Unless this is a restriction of the hosting, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want the `require()` or `include()` function (or `require_once()`). See https://www.php.net/require .

This is also much faster btw, because there is no http connection being setup, but only the internal file system is being queried.

-- EDIT

oh wait, I see you've already found the include function. I think you should use either absolute paths, or use the '..' in the path:

```
include('/full/path/to/the/directory/file.html');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'../123/file.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know 1and1 and what they allow you to do... What I would suggest is have a 3rd folder at the same place as your dmain folders. Call it common. Then in each of your domains folders, where it better suits your needs, create a directory symlink to the common folder we just created...

Basically, it will do this: (absolute blind approximation of actual server)

```
1and1/your_account/123/common -> 1and1/your_account/common <- 1and1/your_account/abc/common
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) so you can open file from both directories.